# How to setup a local proxy so traffic is seen to come from a different IP?

Tags: windows, networking, router, proxy

I have a particular application running on my Windows 10 PC for which I want the traffic to appear to come from a different IP address than the computer uses for everything else. This is so I can apply QoS rules for that traffic on my router. The application in question has settings that allow me to specify a proxy for it to use.

Let's say the standard IP address of my computer is 192.168.1.**2**.
What I'm hoping is that I can run a service as a proxy on this same machine, let's say listening on port 8118. I configure that proxy to send traffic from 192.168.1.**3** (which my router is capable of handling, but because it's different from my main PC, it can handle it differently). Then, I configure my application to use a proxy at localhost:8118 and when the traffic from that application hits the router, it will be seen coming from 192.168.1.**3**, whereas everything else on the PC (not using the proxy) will be seen to come from 192.168.1.**2**

To be clear, I'm not wanting any filtering, logging, rewriting of this traffic - *just* make it come from a different IP address.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: What you want is not possible without a proxy server, assigned to that address you want to use, and only possible if the application even supports using a proxy connection.

Comment: @Ramhound - That sounds OK. Do you know of a suitable proxy server I could install and any hints on how to configure it?

Comment: There are dozens of [proxy servers](https://www.bing.com/search?q=proxy+server+windows&form=EDGTCT&qs=PF&cvid=8ce5a589385c4896b0785ea3e6c74c1f&pq=proxy+server+windows) for Windows out there.  Pick the one you understand how to configure, after, you do some research on the subject.

Comment: @Ramhound Yeah, that's where I'm struggling a little at the moment, hence this question :)

Comment: read our help center.  The fact your asking for a software recommendation here at Superuser,tells me, you have not read it.  There is no incorrect choice.  Like I said you will have to have a separate device, that you can assign that ip address, it won't work on the same computer as the software that is running.

Comment: you may be able to do it without a proxy using routes.  first thing you will need to do in any case is assign the second IP address to your network adapter, since nothing on your computer can use an IP address it doesn't have.  Then you can set which interface to use based on the destination address using routing.  Or you could use a proxy server.  There are several free ones for Windows.